# ECC encryption with Miracle Library in C

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I want to use miracle library in C for simulate some Algorithm. these algorithms are ECC encryption in different coordinate. I have two algorithms that should give me the same output . But I don't know why I can't get it . this is the algorithm that I want to simulate :

[image]
my simulation should give me the same output of this code:

```
fp=fopen("common.ecs","rt");

fscanf(fp,"%d\n",&bits);
mip->IOBASE=16;
cinnum(n,fp);
cinnum(a,fp);
cinnum(b,fp);
cinnum(r,fp);
cinnum(x,fp);
cinnum(y,fp);
mip->IOBASE=16;

printf("modulus is %d bits in length\n",logb2(n));

window = 8  ;
nb = bits   ;

ebrick_init(&binst,x,y,a,b,n,window,nb);

printf("%d elliptic curve points have been precomputed and stored\n",(1<< window));
e = mirvar(2)   ;

printf("--------------------\n");
printf("naive method\n");
ecurve_init(a,b,n,MR_AFFINE);
g = epoint_init();
p = epoint_init();
q = epoint_init();
epoint_set(x,y,0,g);
ecurve_mult(e,g,q);
epoint_get(q,x_calc,y_calc);
cotnum(x_calc,stdout);
cotnum(y_calc,stdout);
printf("--------------------\n");
```

the contents of the common.ecs file is :

192

FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

-3

64210519E59C80E70FA7E9AB72243049FEB8DEECC146B9B1 
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF99DEF836146BC9B1B4D22831
188DA80EB03090F67CBF20EB43A18800F4FF0AFD82FF1012 
07192B95FFC8DA78631011ED6B24CDD573F977A11E794811

According to the above code when I initiate a curve in miracle the points are in Affine coordinate . I should first change them in Jacobian coordinate and then do the next steps. I don't know how to change affine point to Jacobian point . 
a basic problem is that I couldn't understand how miracle initial the curve with this code and give me Doubling.

how can I change these numbers if I want do the steps in paper and compare my result. I mean what numbers can I put instead of this numbers in common.ecs ? I hope I can explain my problems more than before . I am very confused :(

Comment: this site don't let me to put the picture now . please be patient until I do this :)

Comment: From affine to projective: (x,y) -> (x, y, 1). From projective to affine: (x, y, z) -> (x/z^2, y/z^3), as long as z!=0.

Comment: @GregS I do this But my code isn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can verify on the specification pdf of FIPS https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/186/3/archive/2009-06-25/documents/fips_186-3.pdf
that the curve in common.ecs is the NISTP 192 curve.

In effect you have guessed that the first parameter is the size in bits of the prime modulus we work with. The second line corresponds to the prime modulus p in hexadecimal representation (it corresponds to the prime number 2^192-2^64-1). The third line is the coefficient A in the Weierstrass equation of the curve, it accelerates the computation to have A=-3 modulo p (see for example [Guide to elliptic curve cryptography](http://diamond.boisestate.edu/~liljanab/MATH308/GuideToECC.pdf)). The fourth line is the coefficient B in the Weierstrass equation of the curve in hexadecimal. The number in the fourth line as you can see is close (in hexadecimal representation) to the line of the p modulus, it is the order of (the group of points of) the curve (there is Hasse theorem to explain this (you can find it [there](http://www.springer.com/fr/book/9780387094939))). The fifth line is the x-coordinate (in hexadecimal) of a point generator of the group of points of the curve. The sixth line is the y-coordinate (in hexadecimal) of the point generator of the group of points of the curve.